# How should I handle canonical urls in crawler

Tags: web-crawler, canonical-link

how should I handle canonical url in page as Crawler?

For example if I have this in head tag:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://example.com/wordpress/">
```

Should I skip every url which is based on this url and skip them? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The canonical tag is useful when indexing documents into a search engine to reduce the number of duplicates or near-variants which share the same value for the tag. This is how [StormCrawler](http://stormcrawler.net/) uses it for instance.

You could indeed skip indexing URLs which have a different value of canonical but since this is something you discover AFTER you fetched the content, it won't make much difference if you index them anyway using the canonical value as id.

There is an open issue in StormCrawler to leverage the tags [for filtering outlinks](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/issues/315). The advantage of doing this would be that URLs which can be rewritten based on the rules inferred from the canonical tags would not be fetched at all => more efficient crawl.